# Azure python Functions error: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.x509'

Tags: azure-functions

All of my Azure functions have been failing (over the 4 days) with the above error.

I haven't made any changes to the code.

Any ideas?

I tried running the code locally on my laptop. It works fine without any errors.

Comment: Redeploy the app once again.

Comment: Can you provide the details? which Operating system you have used and the Runtime stack?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in case anyone was wondering.

I needed to add

```
cryptography==38.0.4
```

to the requirements.txt file.

A user in the DBT Slack channel helped me so I'll post what he wrote.

---

The Snowflake devs (very frustratingly) only test the Snowflake connector library with exact versions of dependent packages, but at least they provide those specific sets of requirements in their [Git repo](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/tree/main/tested_requirements)

Try including this exact list of requirements in your own file (maybe with a comment and a link to the source, so you don't lose track of it)
[LINK](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/main/tested_requirements/requirements_310.reqs)

```
> # Generated on: Python 3.10.8
asn1crypto==1.5.1
certifi==2022.9.24
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
cryptography==38.0.4
filelock==3.8.2
idna==3.4
oscrypto==1.3.0
pycparser==2.21
pycryptodomex==3.16.0
PyJWT==2.6.0
pyOpenSSL==22.1.0
pytz==2022.6
requests==2.28.1
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.13
snowflake-connector-python==2.9.0
```

The Snowflake library appears to be using undocumented internals from Cryptography that were removed in v39, which was released on Jan 1 2023. It probably broke when the Azure Function updated its dependencies, for whatever reason.

In the future, I strongly recommend using a fully version-pinned requirements file for any kind of "deployed" code, which you can generate using a tool like pip-compile https://pip-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In this case, you would create a requirements.in file with the contents of your original requirements.txt + the Snowflake requirements file. Then you would run something like pip-compile requirements.in to produce a requirements.txt file that contains exact version numbers. You can get even more "strict" by insisting on exact package hash matches, e.g.

```
pip-compile --generate-hashes requirements.in
```

although I'm not sure if Azure supports this.